# UserAccountTeam - Test Class

Tags: unit-test, dml, dml-operations

I have a trigger that basically replicates adding the default team to the account team (it's doing more than just that but for ease of asking this question lets leave it at that case).

How would one go about testing that the trigger is accurately doing it's job when UserAccountTeamMember is an object that one can not perform DML on? Is there any workaround here or will I not be able to test this part of my code?

Comment: Please **[edit]** our post to include your code.

Comment: I don't think the code actually matters in this question (it's complex, across a trigger, domain class, and service class). Overall, I'm just trying to understand if it's even possible to test code that relies on a user's default teams being setup.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you tried querying for it?

Comment: No, I was hoping to not have to rely on querying for active user accounts that contain default teams ;) That said, it's a step I'm more then willing to try at this point! I'll report back.

Comment: Looks like querying will work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot perform DML on it, you have to find existing data that works for you. In this case, I recommend you query for a user who has a `UserAccountTeamMember` set up for them and running as that user for your test.

```
system.runAs([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT UserId FROM UserAccountTeamMember
) LIMIT 1]){
    Test.startTest();
        // do stuff
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll test asap and let you know if this is successful.